# Same this value over different objects

Tags: c++, this

I have the following code:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){
        cout << this << endl;
    }
};

void test()
{
    A a;
}

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        test();
    return 0;
}
```

By right, I would expect during the 2 runs of `test()`, the `this` value for both objects `a` would be different. However I get the same value of `this` for both runs.

Is there something wrong with my reasoning? If not, how do I ensure that the 2 objects of class `A` have different addresses?

Comment: What is your reasoning why they should have different addresses?

Comment: Your successive `test` objects are all re-occupying the same position in the stack. They don't need different addresses, in any case, as no two of them ever co-exist.

Comment: The guy that used to live at 1428, Elm St died and now the guy that moved in after him has the same address as a dead guy used to have. Spooky, isn't it?